# How to publish a Web API of .Net Core and convert the result in a .Zip file

Tags: asp.net-web-api, zip, publish

I have a .Net Core Web API project and I need to convert the content of a "dotnet publish" in a .Zip file, then I need to push it into a repository...

I could use dotnet, msbuild or another tool enable to be automatized.

Note: When I say content published, I mean files which are hosted in the iis. But I don't need to use iis, only the zip.

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/zipdirectory-task?view=vs-2019

```
<Target Name="ZipOutputPath" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <ZipDirectory
        SourceDirectory="$(OutputPath)"
        DestinationFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\output.zip" />
</Target>
```

It works but not entirely. When I run "dotnet publish" a .zip file is created. But it contains only the content of bin directory, it does not contain nugets or packages.

Does anyone know how I can do it.

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by "it does not contain nugets or packages." The nuget packages are resolved when you do a nuget restore and the applicable libraries will be copied to bin directory when you build your project. So the bin directory already contains all the required binaries for running your application.

Comment: Hello @DurgaPrasad, packages are restore in %userprofile%\.nuget\packages folder (windows). They are not restored in bin folder. Could I force it to restore packages in the bin folder?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Comment: Yes, the packages are restored in \.nuget\packages directory. However when we build the solution, msbuild automatically copies all the required binaries to bin folder which are required for running the application. Can I know the problem you are facing? Are the dlls for nuget references not copied into bin folder?

Comment: Yes @DurgaPrasad, .ddls for nuget references are not copied into bin folder. Bin folder only contains dll belong to the project and settings files. However when I publish nuget packares are include too.